# Нужно ли нам столько разных [задач]?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Сейчас на сайте есть 2 идентичных метки [задача](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0) и [задачи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8).
Во-первых, конечно, их надо объединить и синонимизировать.

А во-вторых - не стоит ли эти метки переименовать (во что-то что будет означать логические и собеседовательского уровня задачки) или может вообще удалить?

Если никто не против, то прошу модераторов сделать синонимизацию или бан меток, по выбору.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, обе метки были выпилены.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сняли [задачу]